# Any automatic code formatting tool for GAMS (stand-alone or IDE-integrated)?

Tags: gams-math

I am mainly working in the python ecosystem and am used to automatic code formatters (e.g. Black).

For a new project I have to work with GAMS and a lot of legacy GAMS code.
The GAMS code is by multiple people and without any consistent formatting (or structured formatting at all).
I'd like to change that - if possible in a sustainable and scalable matter.

Are there any automatic code formatters for GAMS, either stand-alone or integrated in an IDE? I haven't been able to find any, which confuses me.